# Davinci Resolve does not import MP3 files in media pool

Tags: windows-10, mp3, video-editing

I am trying to add MP3 files to the media pool of Davinci Resolve. I do so by right clicking and choosing "Import Media ..." (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>). The files are visible and selectable in the file open dialog, but after adding, they do not appear in the media pool.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a hex editor it turned out that the files had the file ending MP3 but were actually WAV files. Changing the extension to WAV (`ren *.mp3 *.wav`) fixed the issue. The WAV files were imported and shown as expected.

[image: WAV file header]